# How to create Fields in tree view with a function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Please I create a wizard like this

[image]

Now I need when I click ***Enregistrer*** Button to create those fields in the tree view on the bottom

**for this example,** I have quantity equal *12* so I need **12 lines** to be created on the **tree view** with the values on the **wizard view**

Comment: You could to add "onchange" function in your One2many field.

Answer (score 0):

You could to add "onchange" function in your One2many field

```
@api.onchange('my_one2many_field')
def onchange_field(self):
    if self.my_one2many_field:
        current_record = self.my_one2many_field[0]
        number_of_lines = current_record.quantity

        all_records = []
        for i in range(0, number_of_lines):
            values = dict()
            values['field_1'] = current_record.field_1
            values['field_n'] = current_record.field_n
            all_records.append((0, 0, values))

        self.my_one2many_field = all_records
```